# Format for <div> tag

Tags: html

I am parsing the html from a site and I encountered this tag: `<div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">`
What attribute does 'data-alert' represent?

Answer (score 2):

These are custom attributes new in HTML 5. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Seems like the page you are talking about uses Foundation CSS framework:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html

Answer (score 0):

See this page:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html

It's a `div` container that, according to the site, conforms to 100% of the container width you put them in.